# Any recommended Code navigation tool for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, navigation, code-analysis

Can anybody recommend a good Delphi source code navigation and analysis tool, which enables code browsing, shows  class hierarchy and evtl. has an editing option? I tried [Code-Navigator](http://www.wellcode.com/home/index.php) which is very fast but i a bit its unstable in complex dependencies.

Comment: I'm facing performance issue cause of comlex package structure which i can'T separate from each other , so i cant navigate or get definiton, and i need alot of luck to get code completion.

Comment: What's so hot about Delphi XE's code navigation? I'm on Delphi 2010, looking for a reason to upgrade...

Comment: @Cosmin: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/whats-new

Comment: I'm tempted to try XE just to see how it goes with multithreaded code in the new sequence diagram generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For navigation and refactoring, I prefer the [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html) IDE expert over anything I have seen before.

It is fast, stable, supports many Delphi versions, has excellent key-bindings (for me, using a mouse is so last century), and supports generics.

It doesn't do repaints over the code-editor (like CodeRush did, and now Castalia does), which can be useful, but it doesn't suffer from painting artifacts either.

Unlike ECO, and the Delphi internal refactoring and ...-Insight tools, it doesn't keep a full model of the whole application and all the libraries it (indirectly) uses. But the tools that do, try to completely emulate the Delphi compiler, and usually fail.

--jeroen

Answer (score 3):

[Castalia for Delphi](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/) has some great features - including (amongst **lots** of other stuff) some code navigation aids.

The only other set of tools I've ever really used in Delphi is [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/), but quite honestly, I can't remember if it included any code navigation features... worth a look nonetheless!

Comment: Thnx for ur Answer, GExperts doesnt have this, i heared about castalia before, but didnt know they provide code navigation, ill try this.

Comment: The GExperts procedure view (Ctrl+G) is a very valuable code navigation tool for me. It saves a lot of time. But it's only for navigation within a unit.

Comment: @The_Fox: right! i love this feature, but as you said only in the same unit, in a bigger code it would be nice to keep the whole source parsed like the GExperts feature. I like the GrepSearch they provide too, although in D2010 it takes much longer than in D7, it would be fabulous if one could keep all keywords in a DB so you can search only the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

[ModelMaker](http://www.modelmakertools.com/)?

or

[GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/)?

or

[Castalia](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/)?

Comment: I have ModelMaker hier, its good to understand existing complex code, but i never used it for navigation, does it provide search options for methode/class names or getting code definition? the Code navigator i used was very fast because it parses the whole code and keeps it in DB, so when you search for methode names you get a very fast results for your search.

Comment: GExperts has some neat features, specially the grep and favorite files but it still no code navigation tool, i need something which parses code and provides fast search results as we have a huge code, the IDE is extremly slow and cause of bad pacage structure is almost unable to provide even code completion.

Answer (score 0):

"As we have a huge code base..."

Our [Source Code Search Engine (SCSE)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) might be helpful.  It uses a language structure aware tokenizer to break you source into tokens, index the set and store the index as a database, and provides the ability to use queries to search across that set using the index rather than a file-by-file scan.  This gives you fast searches that aren't confused by white space or comments. (It will also do grep style searches, but they're a lot slower).

It doesn't construct class hierarchies. It will allow you to access an editor from found hits.